# Como adicionar mais uma condição em uma query usando linq?

Tags: sql-server, linq

Como posso adicionar mais uma condição em um join ?

Tenho a consulta abaixo;

```
 var consultaVeiculo = (from e in dm.Tabela_SegVeiculos
                                       join r in dm.Tabela_VeiculoRefers
                                       on  e.Modelo equals r.Cod_referencia 
                                       into veicRef
                                       from Referencia in veicRef.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                       where e.Seguradora == idSeguradora                                       
                                       orderby e.Modelo_cia
                                       select new { Descricao = Referencia == null ? "" : Referencia.Descricao, e });
```

Ela gera a seguinte query no sql server:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN [t2].[test] IS NULL THEN CONVERT(NVarChar(50),'')
        ELSE CONVERT(NVarChar(50),[t2].[Descricao])
     END) AS [Descricao], [t0].[Seguradora], [t0].[Veic_cia], [t0].[Fabricante], [t0].[Modelo_cia], [t0].[Modelo], [t0].[Categ_AT], [t0].[Situacao], [t0].[Data_inclusao], [t0].[Data_alteracao], [t0].[COD_FIPE]
FROM [dbo].[Tabela_SegVeiculos] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[Descricao], [t1].[Cod_referencia]
    FROM [dbo].[Tabela_VeiculoRefer] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2] ON [t0].[Modelo] = ([t2].[Cod_referencia])
WHERE ([t0].[Seguradora] = 83) AND ([t2].[Cod_referencia] > 0)
ORDER BY [t0].[Modelo_cia]
```

Preciso que logo após o  `ON [t0].[Modelo] = ([t2].[Cod_referencia])` seja adicionado o `and [t2].[Cod_referencia] > 0`.

Já tentei fazer isso da forma abaixo, mas como mostrado na imagem ela exibe um erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para este caso, não use no `Join`. Use no `Where`. Linq não é SQL:

```
var consultaVeiculo = (from e in dm.Tabela_SegVeiculos
                                   join r in dm.Tabela_VeiculoRefers
                                   on e.Modelo equals r.Cod_referencia 
                                   into veicRef
                                   from Referencia in veicRef.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   where e.Seguradora == idSeguradora && r.Cod_referencia > 0                                      
                                   orderby e.Modelo_cia
                                   select new { Descricao = Referencia == null ? "" : Referencia.Descricao, e });
```

Ou ainda, de acordo com o problema do autor:

```
var consultaVeiculo = (from e in dm.Tabela_SegVeiculos
                                   join r in (from ri 
                                              in dm.Tabela_VeiculoRefers 
                                              where ri.Cod_referencia > 0 
                                              select ri)
                                   on e.Modelo equals r.Cod_referencia 
                                   into veicRef
                                   from Referencia in veicRef.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   where e.Seguradora == idSeguradora && r.Cod_referencia > 0                                      
                                   orderby e.Modelo_cia
                                   select new { Descricao = Referencia == null ? "" : Referencia.Descricao, e });
```

Comment: Já tentei assim, só que a query faz com que o Cod_referencia > 0 fique logo no final , preciso de algo que seja depois do ON.

Comment: Por que? O que altera no final?

Comment: Só precisei altera a query para usar sub queries join r in (from ri in dm.Tabela_VeiculoRefers where ri.Cod_referencia > 0 select ri)

Answer (score 2):

```
 var consultaVeiculo = (from e in dm.Tabela_SegVeiculos
            join r in dm.Tabela_VeiculoRefers
            on new { id = e.Modelo, verdadeiro = true } equals new { id = r.Cod_referencia, verdadeiro = r.Cod_referencia > 0}
            into veicRef
            from Referencia in veicRef.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where e.Seguradora == idSeguradora
            orderby e.Modelo_cia
            select new { Descricao = Referencia == null ? "" : Referencia.Descricao, e });
```

Comment: Não consigo entender onde que sua resposta se encaixa na pergunta. **Uma dica**: você não precisa colocar seu código como snippet, você pode só jogar o texto na publicação e usar **`Ctrl + K`** para formatá-lo.

Comment: Retorna (invalid anonymous type member declarator)

Comment: fiz o teste: coloquei nomes nas variáveis do objeto anônimo. funcionou.