# Condição no join ou no where?

Tags: mysql, sql, desempenho, join, where

Existe alguma diferença se eu usar:

```
select * 
from a left join b on a.id = b.id and b.id2=1
where ...
```

ou

```
select * 
from a left join b on a.id = b.id 
where 
b.id2=1
Sent on:
Fri
```

?

O primeiro SQL me retornou super rápido, já o segundo não rodou devido ao MYSQL não conseguir usar o índice de uma campo da tabela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existir, e sua query ainda poder trazer dados divergentes dependendo dos campos usados nos filtros como no exemplo abaixo (*feito em sql server*) problema que tive nessa [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139005/como-adicionar-mais-uma-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-uma-query-usando-linq).

```
declare @tabela1 table(id int , decr varchar(10))

declare @tabela2 table(id int , id2 int null, decr varchar(10))

insert into @tabela1 values
(1, 'tabela 1'),(0, 'tabela 1'),(0, 'tabela 1'),(0, 'tabela 1'),(0, 'tabela 1'),
(0, 'tabela 1'),(0, 'tabela 1'),(0, 'tabela 1'),(0, 'tabela 1'),(0, 'tabela 1'),
(0, 'tabela 1')

insert into @tabela2 values
(1, 1, 'tabela 2'),(1, 2, 'tabela 2'),(0, 1, 'tabela 2'),(0, 1, 'tabela 2')

select * 
from @tabela1 a
left join @tabela2 b
on b.id = a.id and a.id = 1

select * 
from @tabela1 a
left join @tabela2 b
on a.id = b.id 
where a.id = 1
```

Esse é um caso de base de dados não normalizada, onde os dados foram inseridos através de inserts de planilhas(Excel).

Outra coisa;

[Quando você faz `OUTER JOINs (ANSI-89 or ANSI-92)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause), os critérios especificados na `ON` cláusula é aplicado antes do JOIN, mas quando é aplicado na cláusula `WHERE` é aplicada após a junção ser feita. Isso pode produzir muitos conjuntos diferentes de resultados e é claro uma diferença na performance.

Answer (score 3):

Sim existe uma diferença, como pode notar. Pelo menos existe no MySQL atual.

Claro que não vendo a expressão toda (tem uma reticências ali) pode ser que havia um motivo para ser diferente.

Em tese ele poderia ter otimizado ambas igual, só que ele não fez. Quem sabe faça no futuro. Outros bancos de dados podem fazer. Não é algo inerente do SQL.

Esse é um caso possível de otimizar, mas um pouco mais complicado de perceber. As otimizações são feitas sempre que for possível provar matematicamente que ela é vantajosa e que alguém tenha criado um código para isso.

O `JOIN` é completamente desnecessário no SQL. Sempre dá para obter o mesmo resultado sem ele. Ele existe porque dá mais semântica ao intento e facilitar o otimizador perceber o que se deseja e otimizar melhor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -3):

Sim, há uma diferença entre as duas consultas SQL.

Na primeira consulta, você está fazendo um "left join" entre as tabelas "a" e "b", usando duas condições de junção. A primeira condição de junção é "a.id = b.id", que é usada para juntar as duas tabelas, e a segunda condição de junção é "b.id2=1", que é usada para filtrar os resultados do join.

Na segunda consulta, você está fazendo um "left join" entre as tabelas "a" e "b", usando apenas uma condição de junção, que é "a.id = b.id". Em seguida, você está filtrando os resultados do join com a cláusula "where b.id2=1".

A diferença entre as duas consultas é que a primeira consulta usa a segunda condição de junção para limitar os resultados do join antes de aplicar a cláusula "where", enquanto a segunda consulta aplica a cláusula "where" para todos os resultados do join e só depois filtra os resultados.

Isso pode levar a diferenças significativas no desempenho, especialmente se a tabela "b" for grande e não houver um índice adequado para a coluna "id2". Na primeira consulta, a segunda condição de junção é usada para filtrar os resultados do join antes de aplicar a cláusula "where", o que pode tornar a consulta mais eficiente. Na segunda consulta, a cláusula "where" é aplicada a todos os resultados do join, incluindo aqueles que não satisfazem a condição "b.id2=1", o que pode ser menos eficiente.

Se a tabela "b" for grande e a coluna "id2" não tiver um índice adequado, pode ser necessário otimizar a consulta para melhorar o desempenho. Isso pode incluir a criação de um índice para a coluna "id2", ou reescrever a consulta para torná-la mais eficiente.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).